# How to SetVisible a layer without redraw all the mapcanvas

Tags: qgis, layers, c++, api, display

I am working with QGis 2.8.2 API c++/ QT 4.5
I am displaying a lot of layer in a mapcanvas, I am looking for a method like setVisible(boolean ) in order to setvisible or not a specify layer

setVisible is for the QgsMapCanvasLayer
Actually i add a layer in the QList and i refresh the renderer and the mapcanvas  to display it, if i want to hide it i remove it from the qlist and i refresh the renderer and the mapcanvas

but this method is too slow and force me to redraw all the canvas

I don't want t oredraw all the canvas i just want to show or hide a layer

any idea ?